# How to trigger a function call when write/read the value of an int?

Tags: c#, c++

I want to make 2 programs main.exe and control.dll. The language would be C++ or C#.

main.exe is my core algorithm. Control.dll can send some control signal through [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) to main.exe while running. It let other program to control the process of main.exe.

There is a variable `int A` in main.exe. The value of `A` changes during main.exe running. I can also call `Get_A()` or `Set_A()` from control.dll to control the value of A.

But what I want is to export a class `CControl` from control.dll. Then `A` would be a member variable of this class. Anyone call `B=CControl.A` would trigger the `Get_A()`, call `CControl.A = B` would trigger `Set_A()`. So that I can synchronize the value from two sides. And I can also call `CControl.A++` or `+=1`.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Are you maybe asking for properties (which are a feature available in c#)?

Comment: Oh, yes, property. I am not familiar with C#. I should learn more about it. Thanks PlasmaHH!

Comment: Have a look at the c# property syntax [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This might be much easier in C# than in C++. In C++ however, you can capsulate A into a class and overload some operators (like operator=, cast operators etc.) to do something when your value gets read or written.